# Store file to s3 bucket using php Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, minio

please I want to store a file in s3 according to its directory, but when I do this code it saves the string "storage / ;;;" on a file but not the docx with its content??

```
            $path = "storage/uploads/l42fZsuxHTWJhCCh1G9QZVqFVyyjPk8E0046sjAQ.docx";
            Storage::disk('s3')->put("fusiondoc/doc",$path,'public');
```

I also tested with this code by adding Storage :: get but it does not work ?? Thank uu

```
           $path = "storage/uploads/l42fZsuxHTWJhCCh1G9QZVqFVyyjPk8E0046sjAQ.docx";
            $content = Storage::get($path);
            $full_path  = Storage::disk('s3')->put("fusiondoc/doc",$content,'public');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second parameter is content not path, so update like this

```
$path = "storage/uploads/l42fZsuxHTWJhCCh1G9QZVqFVyyjPk8E0046sjAQ.docx";
Storage::disk('s3')->put("fusiondoc/doc/l42fZsuxHTWJhCCh1G9QZVqFVyyjPk8E0046sjAQ.docx",fopen($path),'public');
```

**Update for comment**

```
$fileName = uniqid () . Str::afterLast($path,".");
Storage::disk('s3')->put("fusiondoc/doc/" . $fileName,fopen($path),'public');
```

Comment: Thank uu very much ,it works, but please if i want that instead of writing a name.docx in Storage::put for the file to save, a random name will be generated for the file ?